# Generalized Tate Conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I have seen a statement of the generalized Tate conjecture over finite fields (see for example page 4 of Milne's "The Tate conjecture over finite field" (https://jmilne.org/math/articles/2007e.pdf)).

What is the formulation over arbitrary finitely generated fields?

Comment: You can look at Totaro's survey ( https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2017-54-04/S0273-0979-2017-01588-1/) and at this paper of Ambrosi (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06480).

Comment: The original statement is in 10.3 of GROTHENDIECK, A. 1968. Le groupe de Brauer. III. Exemples et compements, pp. 88–188. In Dix Exposes sur la Cohomologie des Schemas. North-Holland, Amsterdam.